# how to make activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am beginner in Android programming and I want to write a program with 2 activity. The first Activity is this :

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }
}
```

And the Second activity is this :

```
    public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    final String str = "Second Activity";
    final TextView edit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            edit.setText(str);

        }
    });
}
```

But unfortunately the program has a force Stop and I can't find the mistake.
please help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: post your logcat here

Answer (score 1):

```
You have to change the Button name as "button2" in second activity.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your second activity declared inside of your manifest?

If you did not create the second activity as an activity through eclipse or wherever you are working from, and just added it as a new class they will not be linked.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have declared the `SecondActivity` into the `manifest.xml` and then create a new `Button` in your `second_activity.xml` and nominate it with another name. You have already used `button1`.

```
    public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
      @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
       final String str = "Second Activity";
       final TextView edit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
       final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); <!-- for example
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        edit.setText(str);

    }
});
}
```